# Add conditional column with multiple conditions in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Raw materials can appear in the column of the TopMaterial as well as in the column of the component.
The empty rows show that there is no component here, but e.g. a service.
In the example, I see that the component 00800700 flows into the TopMAterial 7158.

I do not need the information that the material 080007000 flows into the TopMaterial of the same name. However, I can only remove the lines if I take the unique Calc No. into account.

So I would like to generate a new column that queries in the first step whether the TopMaterial corresponds to the component. If this is the case, the rows with the corresponding Calc No. should all be empty.

[Example new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUeoM.png)

Comment: What if for the same Calc Number .. there are multiple items in the Material column, some of them match TopMaterial and some dont. Which do I use?

Comment: The calc no. is always related to the top material. Therefore, a top material always has only one calc no. It can happen that the top material itself is a component. But then there will be a new calc Nr related to the new top material. 
The case that a top material simultaneously matches one component and does not match another does not occur

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

See if this works. Assumes if there are ANY matches between Top Material and Material that all of matching Calc Numbers becomes null, even if there is another combination for that Calc Number that is false

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Material] <> null)),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each if [Top Material]=[Material] then 1 else 0),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = 1)),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows1", {"Calc Number"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Calc Number"}, #"Removed Duplicates", {"Calc Number"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Custom"}, {"Custom"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", "Output", each if [Custom]=1 then null else [Top Material]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in   #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach of filling in the values downwards does not work because some of the values must also be filled in upwards.
Raw materials can appear in the column of the TopMaterial as well as in the column of the component. 
The empty rows show that there is no component here, but e.g. a service.
In the example, I see that the component 00800700 flows into the TopMAterial 7158. 
I do not need the information that the material 080007000 flows into the TopMaterial of the same name. However, I can only remove the lines if I take the unique Calc No. into account.

Comment: I thought it might not work. Please explain in your question by editing it, which group of columns you are bucketing, and how the methodology works.  It may be just me, but I'm not sure what you are looking for since the explanations were incomplete

Comment: I have adjusted my question. I hope this makes it clearer. Thanks already

Comment: I have adjusted my answer. Let me know if that works